# Stop/Start Slider - Stop after one cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have a project that I am working on that uses Start/Stop slider by Chris Coyier shown here http://css-tricks.com/startstop-slider. The client loves it, but now wants it to to just cycle through once and stop. Also after it cycles and stops the "Stop" button to turn to "Start" so that if the user wants to play it again they can.

I am a newbie at jquery/Javascript and am having no luck figuring this out.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `doMove` function and clear the interval after the slide has completed 1 revolution

```
if (movement == tooFar) {
  $(".slide img").animate({
    "top": -200
  }, function() {
    $("#mover").animate({
      "left": 0
    }, function() {
      $(".slide img").animate({
        "top": 20
      });
    });
  });

  clearInterval(sliderIntervalID);
  $("#slider-stopper").text("Start");
}
```

Comment: Thanks devmatt for your answer. However that didn't seem to work. Maybe I am doing something wrong

Comment: If you can send through your JS code using http://jsfiddle.net/ I might be able to find out why.